# Tiny mce is adding extra p tags when copied from outlook or word

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tinymce

I think my earlier question was too large, I am trying to put some minimal content.

**Problem:**

```
When I am trying to copy some content from word/outlook to tinymce, any text after bullet points/numbers is getting discarded when writing to word.
```

**Example:**

When I copy  below contnet, I am not seeing Bullet1 and Bullet2 in final word document

*Word bullets test IE
 •  Bullet1
•   Bullet2*

**My xslt code:**

```
<xsl:template match="qnap:li">

  <xsl:variable name="paraStyle" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="parent::qnap:ol">AnswerNumbered</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>AnswerBullet</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not(qnap:p)">
    <xsl:variable name="paraContent" as="element()">
      <span>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </span>
    </xsl:variable>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:variable name="paraContent" as="element()">
      <span>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="qnap:p"/>
      </span>
    </xsl:variable>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Hope this is not creating any confusion. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: please add the smallest correct document that illustrates your problem (so people can cut/paste for testing). Good luck.

Comment: @potame I have added more content of my xml.

Comment: @potame Tinymce is the one which is doing this. When we copy content from outlook/word into tiny mce extra p tags are been added.

Comment: @62071072SP Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try copy paste from outlook/word into notepad(++) first, then copy paste from there into S.O. posting. Should strip out any faux-html (but maybe not!) . Good luck.

Comment: @potame please find edit to my question.

Comment: It's confusing...Is it an XSL-T issue or is just related to copy-paste between Word and tinymce? If it is XSL-T, what is the input XML that is submitted to XSL transformation? If it is not XSL-T, consider re tagging your question and changing the title.

Comment: @potame Hi, yes you were right its a tiny mce problem hence I have changed my title.But I want my xslt handle those p tags